# Passing AWS credentials to Docker application running on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I have created a docker application running on ECS that I would like to be able to access AWS S3.
I am passing my AWS credentials as env. variables to the `aws_ecs_task_definition` resource in terraform:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app_task" {
 family                   = "app-first-task" # Name your task
 container_definitions    = <<DEFINITION
 [
  {
    "entryPoint" : [...],
    ...

    "environment": [
            {
                "name": "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
                "value": "${var.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
            },
            {
                "name": "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
                "value": "${var.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
            },
            {
                "name": "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN",
                "value": "${var.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}"
            }
      ]
   ...
```

I have the following questions:

1. Is this a secure enough approach and a best practice ?
2. If this approach is secure, how can I update the env. variables - would re-setting them in my local
   environment and running `terraform apply` work ?

Comment: You should almost definitely assign your ECS task an IAM role; [Identity and Access Management for Amazon Elastic Container Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/security-iam.html) and [Task IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html).  It's almost never a best practice to pass around AWS credentials directly as you show.

Comment: That is definitely **NOT** best practice. Using a Task IAM role is best practice. The entire purpose of the Task IAM role is to provide AWS credentials to your software running inside the container. Please use that instead.